# php special character validation

Tags: php, html

I made a simple form where the user needs to enter their name and email adress, after the user has
done this they should click on the submit button and their data show for 3 seconds and after that they will be redirected to another page.

All this works but now i want to add a input validation i found a example on W3Schools and tried make this and add this to my code. Right now my code looks like this but the validation doesnt work. how can i fix this problem?

the validation doesnt show up so when a user for example puts a 2 behind his/her name the code wont give the error message: `$NameErr = "only letters and white space are allowed";` instead of show this it goes straight to the "next page" were the user input is show for a short time

```
<?php
    $NameErr = "";
    $Message = false;
    $Name = $_POST["Fullname"];
    $Email = $_POST["Email"];

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        if(empty($_POST["Fullname"])){
            $NameErr = "name is required";
        }else{
            $Message = "your data has been sent, you will be forwarded to the next page.";
            $Name = $_POST["Fullname"];
        }
            $Name = Input($_Post["Fullname"]);
            if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$Name)){
                $NameErr = "only letters and white space are allowed";
            }
        }

        if(empty($_POST["Email"])){
            $EmailErr = "Email is required";
        }else{
            $Message = "your data has been sent, you will be forwarded to the next page.";
            $Email = $_POST["Email"];
        }
            $Email = Input($_Post["Email"]);
            if(!filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                $EmailErr = "Only letters are allowed";
            }
        
    
    function Input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
        }
    ?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
   <title>form</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formulier.css">
</head>
<body>

<main>
    <?php
        if(!$Message){
    ?>
    <p> put your data here: </p>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $NameErr;?></span>
        <input type="text" name="Fullname" placeholder="enter your fullname">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $EmailErr;?></span>
        <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="enter your email">
        <button name="SubmitBtn">submit</button>
    </form>

    <?php
        }else{
            ?>
            <h1 id="Message"> your data is:</h1>
            <p><b>Naam:</b> <?php echo $Name; ?></p>
            <p><b>E-mail:</b> <?php echo $Email; ?></p>
            <p id="Message"><?php echo $Message; ?></p>

            <script>
                var Message = document.getElementById("Message");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location = "contact.php";
                }, 3000);
            </script>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</main>

   
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a good problem description. What happens that isn't supposed to? What doesn't happen that is supposed to? Can you give us an example of a value that fails? Or maybe there are some errors/warnings/notices?

Comment: there are no erros/warning etc. i did an example to the question now

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](https://3v4l.org/Xj112).

Comment: I get what you did there but whenever i put something like that in my code it doesnt work. like it still will redirect to the next page  and wont show the error next to the input field

Comment: That's because you always define `$Message` whenever your values aren't empty. You need to do all the checks first and define `$Message` only if all conditions are satisfied.

Comment: you mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/zjo9m1d5/

Comment: That has both syntax and logic errors. But you have the right general idea. You don't need additional variables, just check if an error exists (`$NameErr` or  `$EmailErr`) and if either does, don't set the message.